# Detect two finger gesture

Tags: javascript, react-native, gesture

I have a PanGesture handler that is nested in a ScrollView, which hence should only handle pinch gestures with two fingers, but let the parent handle all other gestures.

From reading the docs, `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` would be the right place to determine whether to handle the gesture, but unfortunately, `gestureState.numberActiveTouches` is always `1`, so I can't tell whether the user is going to tap, pinch or swipe.

Also, it's not like that method would be invoked two times with a short delay if I tap the screen with two fingers and start pinching, so I really wouldn't know how to detect that case.

Any advice?

**Edit**

`View.onTouchStart` would fire twice in a row for two fingers, so I could easily detect an upcoming pinch gesture and set a flag for the PanResponder. However, the responder's `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` always fires before I get those two events, whether I declare `onTouchStart` on a nested view, the parent view, or the view that owns the ParentResponder, so I'm too late here.

Comment: find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` should only return true or false. So with

```
...
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true
...
```

you are telling the responder to handle touches and with

```
...
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true
...
```

to handle movement and drag gestures. Then you can use

```
...
onPanResponderGrant: (event, gesture) => {

}
onPanResponderStart: (event, gesture) => {
    let activeTouches = gesture.numberActiveTouches;
}
...
```

to get your active touches. If you have trouble getting the right responder to handle your input in a nested situation, try looking into `onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture` at the bottom of the gesture responder system docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html)